# Elements leak out of center column when zooming

Tags: css, html

Here is the site: http://magicdynamic.com/zoom/

I'm using Google Chrome, and the upper-right elements are leaking out of the main column with very strong zoom.

Since the zoom needs to be very strong, it should not be a big problem, but I want to understand why does it behave that way.

I tried both 400px and 30% as margin for headerBar, but it still leaks out.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because you `div#midColumn` has `margin: 0 auto` (so it is centered) but the background image in on you body. So if you zoom too hard, the left page margin's are gone, which moves your `div`s relative to the background image.

So you could try to make the `body` background blue and put the page image on the `div#midColumn`.

Answer (score 0):

add some properties to in your stylesheet

1. div#midColumn -> add to overflow: hidden;
2. div#header -> add to overflow: hidden;